# websockets, express.js and can’t establish a connection to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

This is simple chat on [WS](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and `express.js`. I get the error that the browser can't connect to server via `websockets`.

client connection:

```
file: rtc.html 
ws = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.hostname + '/wr' );
ws.onerror = (error) => { console.log(error); };
ws.onmessage = (message) => {
   . . .
```

Server code:

```
const express =   require('express');
const http =      require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();

app.get('/rtc', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile('/home/user/dev/rtc.html');
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server:server, path: "/wr" });

. . . 

app.listen(3000);
```

UPD: The problem was due to the fact that I was doing chat on `webrtc` and tested in `Mozilla` and `Mozilla` would not connect without `https` connection however `getUserMedia` ran fine.
It was necessary to write so:

```
var https = require('https');
var serv = https.createServer(serverConfig, app);
```

Comment: Which server-side webSocket library are you using?

Comment: that: https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change from:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

to:

```
server.listen(3000);
```

When you use `app.listen()`, it creates a new http server and thus the one you connected socket.io to is never started.  To fully understand `app.listen()`, the code for it looks like this:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, you can see it was creating a different http server than the one you attached your webSocket server to and thus that other one was never started.

---

Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
const server = app.listen(3000);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server:server, path: "/wr" });
```

And, not create your own http server at all.  `app.listen()` returns the new server object that it created.

Comment: I replaced:
`app.listen(3000);`
to:
`server.listen(3000);` but still not connection

Comment: @alex10 - Then you need to do some troubleshooting/debugging.  In the Chrome browser, look at the network tab in the debugger and see exactly what is happening from the client when your page is loaded.  In particular, you will be looking for the attempt to connect on the webSocket and see what is returned (or not) from that.  If you don't know how to open the Chrome debugger in your page when it is loaded, then Google that and you should find plenty of info on how to do that.  You will want the network tab to be able to see what happens with your webSocket connection.

Comment: I kind of found what was the problem. At the end of the matter written, the problem was weird.

Comment: You gave the correct answer. I had the question to include more details.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was missing :)

Answer (score 1):

just make sure you use server.listen().Rest the code speaks itself

```js
   var express         = require('express'),
     app             = express(),
     http            = require('http'),
     server          = http.createServer(app),
     WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
     wss             = new WebSocketServer({ server });
 
 
 
 app.use(express.static(__dirname));
 
 server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {  //
 console.log("Node server is running on http://localhost:3000/"); });
 
 wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
    //console.log("New connection.");
    ws.on('message', function (message) {
        //console.log("Message received:", message);
    });
```